# Validating Json in Scala/Play 2.3.x

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm having trouble converting JSON values to anything other than Strings.  The code below gives me an error like the following:

```
JsError(List((/id,List(ValidationError(error.expected.jsnumber,WrappedArray()))))
```

However, if I change the type for the constructor parameters of ConfigInfo and ConfigInfoReads to String, everything works as expected.  The Play docs show that conversion from JsNumber to Long and JsBoolean to Boolean should just work by default.

```
// Defined in my controller
implicit val ConfigInfoReads: Reads[ConfigInfo] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").read[Long] and
  (JsPath \ "newRecord").read[Boolean]
)(ConfigInfo.apply _)

// Defined in my controller
case class ConfigInfo(id: Long, newRecord: Boolean)

// Inside of my controller action
request.body.asJson.map { json =>
  val config = json.validate[ConfigInfo]
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example of the JSON being passed:

```
{"id":"4","newRecord":"false"}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read `Double` as `Long` ?

Comment: Sorry about that, it was a typo.

Comment: What about sample json? And `Boolean` - `String` ??

Comment: Added sample JSON and corrected the other typo.

Comment: `"4"` is not a number, it's a string containing the character '4', hence the error message `error.expected.jsnumber`.

Comment: Correct.  This actually brings up a different issue.  The JSON in question is sent via a JQuery AJAX call and for some reason my controller always responds with a 400 unless I call JSON.stringify() on my JSON object before sending the request.  Stringifying the JSON seems to be the accepted solution from what I see in other StackOverflow posts but obviously this causes the issue I currently have.